# flatMap内での再帰呼び出しの最適化

Tags: scala

現在Functional Programming in Scalaの日本語訳を読んでいます。exercise 4.5のtraverse関数を実装せよという問題に関しての質問です。

```
def traverse[A,B](as:List[A])(f:A=>Option[B]):Option[List[B]]= as match{
 | case Nil => Some(Nil)
 | case (h::t) => for{
 | hh <- f(h)
 | tt <- traverse(t)(f)
 | } yield(hh::tt)
 | }

 traverse: [A, B](as: List[A])(f: A => Option[B])Option[List[B]]
```

この関数は正常に動くようですが、

```
traverse((1 to 10000).toList)(i => Some(i))
```

と長さが一万程度のlistでstackoverflowになってしまいます。
flatMap内で再帰しているので末尾再帰にできません。
flatMapで再帰する関数でstacksafeにするにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この本のGitHubにあるヒントと答えを見ると、`foldRight`で`traverse`を実装できるよ、と書いてあります（答えを先に見るのが嫌な人は、1つめのリンクだけクリックしてください）。

https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/errorhandling/05.hint.txt
https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/errorhandling/05.answer.scala

ここで、第3章のエクササイズを一通りやっていれば、`List.foldRight`を末尾再帰に実装する方法も出てきたはずです。その方法で実装されている`foldRight`を使えば、`traverse`もスタックセーフに実装できると思います。（Scala標準のListも`foldRight`は末尾再帰で実装されているようなので、多分そのままでスタックセーフに動くのではないでしょうか。）

Comment: Scala標準のfoldRightは(少なくとも現時点で最新の2.11.6で)reverseしてfoldLeftしてるだけで、末尾再帰ではありません
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L396-L397
(foldRightが呼び出しているfoldLeftも末尾再帰ではなくwhile) https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L119-L128

Comment: この実装はスタックセーフですし僕にも理解できます　ありがとうございます
`[Option[List[B]]]` これがないと型をNilに合わせちゃうんですね・・

Answer (score 1):

方法はいくつかあるかもしれませんが、とりあえずScalazではDList(差分リスト)を使っています

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.1/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala#L44-L60

Comment: scalazすごいけど難しいですね。。
traverseのように '>>= ' , 'flatMap' 内から再帰する場合　スタックセーフにするためには
モナド共通の解決法のようなものはなくてそれぞれに対応するという事なんでしょうか
このscalazの実装も
[https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/errorhandling/05.answer.scala]
のfoldrを使った実装と原理は一緒でしょうか